# Ubuntu 16.04 does not give reboot message before going for reboot.

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, sudo, reboot

I tried to 'sudo reboot' of a ubuntu 16.04 machine( say machine A) from another machine(say machine B). I get the response as false (gives exit status as -1)  yet machine A goes for rebooting. When I give same command for rebooting machine 14.04 it gives me response True and goes for rebooting.

Why is there a difference ? could anybody explain?

Machine_A - irb>

```
system("sudo sshpass -p 'password' ssh -v -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 1234 machine_B@z.z.z.z 'sudo reboot'")
```

Also, when I execute 'sudo reboot' command on ubuntu 14.04 it gives me following message-

```
Broadcast message from ubuntu@machine
    (/dev/pts/5) at 12:12 ...

The system is going down for reboot NOW!
```

Whereas ubuntu 16.04 does not give any such message and just says

```
Connection to z.z.z.z closed by remote host.
Connection to z.z.z.z closed.
```

Why doesnt it display the message?

I referred 'https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1488' post for solution but I did not get any.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you type `mesg` in machine A, what is the output?

Comment: output is: is y

Comment: output is : is y @GeorgeUdosen